# Update Bootstrap without change theme

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a project with Bootstrap 2.3.2, with the default theme. I made a upgrade to version 3.3.2 (current today).

Now the layout of the components are changed. For example, the navbar is now more white, flat, and with less shadow. My client (The person I'm doing the app) didn't like the new style.

So is there a way to get 3.3.2.css with 'same' final result of '2.3.2'?
(I know somethings will change but in most of cases like navbar.)

Comment: Honestly, I think you'll have to manually go through and overwrite the new bootstrap styles to make them look like the old ones

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap 3 is substantially different from Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). It's rewritten to be mobile-first, many class names have changed, styles in some of those renamed classes have changed, and you can't just upgrade the core bootstrap files and expect everything to be the same. See [Bootstrap's migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) for more information. Migrating is not a trivial process. If you're not ready to take that on, I suggest you stick with BS2 until you are.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class names as per the guide from getbootstrap.com

[Migration Link](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/)

example if your navbar class is

```
<div class="navbar nav">
```

change it to

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
```